# Is it okay to use async: false if calling for small data?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm mainly asking this to know what's the best practice with regards to getting small data from the server.

Like for one example, I'm using an ajax(or sjax. lol) call to check if there are new Notifications for a user

```
    function checkNewNotifs() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/CheckNewNotifications',
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data == 'True') {
                    $('#alert-icon').css('color', '#FF4136');
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

It gets the job done, but I'm thinking if there's a better way of achieving this?

I'm mainly using ASP.NET MVC 4/5 as of the moment to provide context.

---

**Edit:**
For the future ajax beginner readers like myself, the proper way of achieving something similar to this is through `.done()` I haven't completely grasped the idea of ajax yet, but a lot can be done through the following call:

```
    function checkNewNotifs() {
        $.when(
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Home/CheckNewNotifications',
                success: function (data) {
                    //do data manipulation and stuff.
                }
            })).done(function() {
                //append to view
            })
    }
```

**tl;dr async: false = bad**

Comment: But why do you use `sync` request instead `async`? What are the reasons?

Comment: The problem is not about the size of the data, but about the time of the networking.

Comment: I don't get why I got a downvote, is this question not valid? Can someone carw to explain?

Comment: @idlerboris I need it to be sync because I need real time data. I need to do a check and get the answer before doing anything else. I've read around here that ajax shouldn't be used for this since the a in ajax means asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason why **you should avoid sync request**s is a **hang outs of UI**.

Is there a reason why do you use sync requests?

I think you should **use async requests to check notifications**, because in case when request will take a bit more time than you expect - user will not see any freezing of UI.

Especially this problem will be actual for users with slow internet connection or slow connection to your server (different country, or event different continent).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! For this implementation, I used a aync because I needed to check if there are notifications available before doing the rest of my actions. For that case, is using async still wrong?